# How to get tasklist information from cmd, without using "tasklist" command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, tasklist

Anyone knows how to extract the tasklist information using cmd, but without using "tasklist /svc" command?

Comment: That's like asking if anyone knows how to walk with no legs. Or how to eat with no mouth. Why would you want to avoid using the tool that solves your problem?

Comment: Yes, I use `tasklist` without the `/svc` option.

Comment: because taskist did not execute through nmap's psexec. The answer below worked perfectly BTW

Comment: I think it is better if you are more specific in asking your question, because honestly it does not make any sense what you are trying to ask!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use WMIC, something like :

```
WMIC PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid
```